# TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined. when using mongodb atlas but no error when using mongodb locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i get the error when i use the mongodb atlas but when using the mongodb locally(mongo installed on my computer) the code runs very well with no errors.

```
http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("Server started");

mongoClient.connect("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@myname.anjzd.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority", function(error, client){
   var database = client.db("mydatabase");
   console.log("Database connected.");
});
```

Comment: You should make it a habit to log and return on errors when a callback provides you one. In this case you can see that since the callback function calls (error, client), if an error arises the client will be null. If there's an error, log it and return and it will give you more information as to why you can't connect.

Comment: found the right way, i change the code to the following http.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log("Server started");

const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@me.anjzd.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new mongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const database = client.db("mydatabase");
  console.log("Database Connected");

Comment: thanks for taking a try on it

Comment: What value does `error` have when the problem occurs?

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846151/typeerror-cannot-read-property-db-of-undefined-while-trying-to-mongodb-atlas

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've got an `error` from this callback and therefore your `client` will be set to `null`.

I guess the error comes from your URL that you put inside `connect`.
`<username>`, `<password>` and `<dbname>` are placeholders for your real username, password and database name respectively.
say your real username, password and database are `ABC`, `123` and `myDB` respectively, then your connection URL would be something like this:

```
let url = "mongodb+srv://ABC:123@myname.anjzd.mongodb.net/myDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

If the error is caused by something else you can handle it properly to detect the reason.

```
mongoClient.connect(url, function(error, client){
  if (error) return console.log(error);
  var database = client.db("mydatabase");
  console.log("Database connected.");
});
```